# How to get map element by key object?

Tags: typescript, types

Thereis a code:

```
let a = new Map<{id: number, age: number}, string>();

a.set({id: 1, age: 20}, "1");

console.log(a.get({id:1, age: 20}));
```

It gives me `undefined` because object added to map and looking object are not equals. Is it possible to make complicate key in map to retrive it when?

I can do this:

```
  let a = new Map<string, string>();
```

Where string key is concatination: `id_age`, but I dislike this, because it is not obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects work by reference, and not by value. That means that `{ a: 5, b: 6 } !== { a: 5, b: 6 }`

What you can do is create a class that has a custom `equals` method that compares properties by value, instead of the object key you currently have:

```
export default class Person {
  public id: number;
  public age: number;
  
  constructor(id: number, age: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public equals(obj: any): boolean {
    return obj && typeof obj === 'object' && obj.id === this.id && obj.age === this.age;
  } 
}
```

And then use it in your Map:

```
const map = new Map<Person, string>();

map.set(new Person(1, 20), '1');
console.log(map.get(new Person(1, 20)); // '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a `value` (an `object`) on `Map`, then You should have object reference when you want to get the `value` from the object,

Because not two same object are equal in JS, `{} !== {}`

```js
let a = new Map();

const o = { id: 1, age: 20 };
a.set(o, "1");

console.log(a.get(o));
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, so to do that I need to `o` object to operate with map or some maps, right?

Comment: That's right, You need the same object when you add `object` and also when getting the value from the map.